# Remove a comment on every line if it is present

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a small data set like the one below contained within < filename >:

```
##standby!##hellow how are you1
##standby!##hellow how are you2
#how do you do
##standby!##hellow how are you4
am good jane
##standby!##hellow how are you5
```

Now I have to check if the string `##standby!##` is present and occurs at the start of any given line and if it does then remove it.

If the string `##standby!##` is not available on the start of that line skip that line and continue with rest of the file.

I tried this:

```
sed '/^#/ d' <filename>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to use POSIX compliant arguments to `sed` in order to use this command portably across platforms:

```
sed 's/^##standby!##//g' file > newfile
```

Only the options -efn are supported by POSIX `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^##standby!##//' file
hellow how are you1
hellow how are you2
#how do you do
hellow how are you4
am good jane
hellow how are you5
```

`^##standby!##` will match the pattern at start and replacement is just an empty string. `-i.bak` is for inline editing.

Comment: I think you must skip `am good jane`: if the word ##standby!## is not available on the start of that line skip that line and continue with rest of the file.

Comment: It seems the OP intends to remove every lines that contain `##standby!##`. My second understanding is to remove the words like you did, but don't process (meaning remove) the line `am good jane`. Of course only the OP knows what he really wanted. Cheers.

Comment: @RajMullapu: If this doesn't solve your problem then you should clarify these questions and provide your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

`perl -pe 's/##standby\!##//g' filename`

Produces this output:

```
hellow how are you1
hellow how are you2
#how do you do
hellow how are you4
am good jane
hellow how are you5
```

`-p` loops through each line, printing it after processing
`-e` executes the perl code
`s/foo/bar/g` substitutes